# start jaxl (php xmpp client) server from iOS client

Tags: php, macos, webserver, xmpp

I have created an xmpp client for the iPhone.
I want to receive remote notifications for when someone messages me and iPhone client is off.
Therefore I needed to connect to behind-the-scenes xmpp client using php.
I am currently connecting using NSURLConnection like this:

```
NSString * url = [http://my_mac_ip_address/some_folder/jaxlcode/examples/xmpp_client?device_token=%@&another_field=%@, deviceToken, anotherField];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection * urlConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
```

On jaxl code I changed argv[0], argv[1], argv[2] arguments using php to get arguments, so that I can use NSURLConnection.
When I start server directly from terminal connection always starts up, and authenticates succesfully (via php script arg1 arg2 arg3). My issue is when I start server from chrome browser or using NSURLConnection (which I believe) is same as starting from browser. The code times out more than 50% of the time.

Is there any other way to start server, or create more stable connection to jaxl php xmpp client server?

Comment: https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL

Comment: That is something you are trying to achieve. To make it clear for myself, all that you are trying to do is to communicate with jaxl client running on some remote server. Is it?